# Twitter bootstrap dropdown + bootstrap-multiselect

Tags: javascript, ruby, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have twitter bootstrap dropdown list on a page

```
.btn-group
    %a.btn.dropdown-toggle{"data-toggle"=>"dropdown", href: "#"}
      Test
      %span.caret
    %ul.dropdown-menu#dropdown-menu-test1
      - if data.any?
        - data.each do |account|
          %li
            %label.checkbox
              %input{ type: :checkbox, value: some_value, name: "test", checked: some_condition}some data
```

I works good but I want to convert it to https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect. To do that I have to replace `%ul - %li` with `%select - %option` which what I did.

```
  %select{class: "multiselect", multiple:"multiple", id: "multiselect-test", name: "multiselect-test-name"}
    %option
      test1
    %option
      test2
```

But it turned out that there was no ability to check some options on page load. There is more, `params["multiselect-test-name"]` is nil.

So how do I handle these two issues: lack of ability to have some options check on page load (which depends of `some_condition`) and lack of `params["multiselect-test-name"]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try options like this `options_for_select(["test1", "test2", "test3"])`

for example:

```
%select{class: "multiselect", multiple:true, id: "multiselect-test", name: "multiselect-test-name", options_for_select(["test1", "test2", "test3"])}
```

it will work for you inshaAllah..